# Inject specific values to specific constructor parameters with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have some dependencies that can be modified in the field via a config file, and I am trying to specify some construtor parameters.

I have a module (which will be registered with the Simple Injector container), the constructor should always contain a Guid for systemId and a dictionary for the settings. It may contain constructor for other items such as a ILogger etc:

```
public interface IMonitor
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}

public class DevLinkMonitor : IMonitor
{
    public DevLinkMonitor(Guid systemId, Dictionary<string,string> settings)
    {
        // store the injected parameters
    }

    public void Start() {}

    public void Stop() {}
}
```

I then have a class which manages the construction of the monitor objects:

```
_monitorManager.Add(
    Guid.NewGuid(),
    "System A London",
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "IpAddress", "192.168.1.2" },
        { "Password", "password" }
    },
    typeof(DevLinkMonitor));

_monitorManager.Add(
    Guid.NewGuid(),
    "System B Mars",
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "IpAddress", "192.168.100.10" },
        { "Password", "password" }
    },
    typeof(DevLinkMonitor));
```

On construction of the monitor object I would like to inject the specific Guid ID and specific settings dictionary (done in `CreateAndRun()`):

```
public class MonitorManager
{
    internal class Item
    {
        public readonly string Description;
        public readonly Dictionary<string, string> Settings;
        public readonly Type TypeToCreate;
        public IMonitor Instance { get; set; }

        public Item(string description, Dictionary<string, string> settings, Type typeToCreate)
        {
            Description = description;
            Settings = settings;
            TypeToCreate = typeToCreate;
        }
    }

    private readonly Container _container;
    readonly Dictionary<Guid, Item> _list = new Dictionary<Guid, Item>();

    public MonitorManager(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Add(Guid id, string description, Dictionary<string, string> settings, Type typeToCreate)
    {
        if(typeToCreate.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMonitor)))
           throw new ArgumentException($"{typeToCreate} does not implement {typeof(IMonitor)}", nameof(typeToCreate));

        _list.Add(id, new Item(description, settings, typeToCreate));
    }

    public void CreateAndRun()
    {
        foreach (var item in _list)
        {                
            var id = item.Key; // this is the guid we want to inject on construction
            var value = item.Value;
            var settings = value.Settings; // use this settings dictionary value on injection

            // for each below call, somehow use the values id, and settings
            value.Instance = _container.GetInstance(value.TypeToCreate) as IMonitor;
            if (value.Instance == null)
                throw new InvalidCastException($"Does not implement {typeof(IMonitor)} ");

            value.Instance.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        foreach (var value in _list.Select(item => item.Value))
        {
            value.Instance.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible with Simple Injector? Or does anyone smell a code smell?

Comment: I think you should move the Guid and the Dictionary out of the constructor and make them arguments of the `Start` method. Seems to me that they are part of the contract of `IMonitor`.

Comment: Agreed @Steven, in the end I created the type manually via a proxy and then used SimpleInjector to find the dependencies and passed them to the constructor myself. This way could avoid lots of null checks, as per answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted the flexibility of SimpleInjector to create types, without the code smell of defining contracts in my constructor - as Steven rightly said this should form part of IMonitor.

The thing I didnt like about having things being created in Start() is if Stop() was called before Start()... the plugin framework should of course ensure this is not possible but nonetheless I consider it good practice to put null reference checks on things I am going to use within the class and this bloats code to one extent or the other.

```
public void Stop()
{
    // although unlikely, we would fail big time if Stop() called before Start()
    if(_someService != null && _fileService != null)
    {
        _someService .NotifyShutdown();
        _fileService.WriteLogPosition();
    }   
}
```

So instead I went for a plugin architecture with a factory approach, in to the factory I pass a SimpleInjector container which it can use to construct any type it likes.

```
public interface IMonitorFactory
{
    void RegisterContainerAndTypes(Container container);
    IMonitor Create(Guid systemId, Dictionary<string,string> settings);
}

public class DevLinkMonitorFactory : IMonitorFactory
{
    private Container _container;

    public void RegisterContainerAndTypes(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;

        // register all container stuff this plugin uses
        container.Register<IDevLinkTransport, WcfTransport>();

        // we could do other stuff such as register simple injector decorators
        // if we want to shift cross-cutting loggin concerns to a wrapper etc etc
    }

    public IMonitor Create(Guid systemId, Dictionary<string,string> settings)
    {           
        // logger has already been registered by the main framework
        var logger = _container.GetInstance<ILogger>();

        // transport was registered previously
        var transport = _container.GetInstance<IDevLinkTransport>();

        var username = settings["Username"];
        var password = settings["Password"];

        // proxy creation and wire-up dependencies manually for object being created
        return new DevLinkMonitor(systemId, logger, transport, username, password);
    }
}
```

The MonitorManager now has a couple of extra tasks to wireup the initial ContainerRegistration and then call the Create for each. Of course the factory doesnt need to use SimpleInjector but makes life a lot easier should the main framework provide services that the plugin will use.

Also since the object created via a factory with all required parameters in the constructor there is no need for lots of null checks.

```
public interface IMonitor
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}

public class MonitorManager
{
    internal class Item
    {
        public readonly string Description;
        public readonly Dictionary<string, string> Settings;
        public IMonitorFactory Factory { get; set; }
        public IMonitor Instance { get; set; }

        public Item(string description, Dictionary<string, string> settings, IMonitorFactory factory)
        {
            Description = description;
            Settings = settings;
            Factory = factory;
        }
    }

    private readonly Container _container;
    readonly Dictionary<Guid, Item> _list = new Dictionary<Guid, Item>();

    public MonitorManager(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    // some external code would call this for each plugin that is found and
    // either loaded dynamically at runtime or a static list at compile time
    public void Add(Guid id, string description, Dictionary<string, string> settings, IMonitorFactory factory)
    {
        _list.Add(id, new Item(description, settings, factory));
        factory.RegisterContainerAndTypes(_container);
    }

    public void CreateAndRun()
    {
        foreach (var item in _list)
        {                
            var id = item.Key; // this is the guid we want to inject on construction
            var value = item.Value;
            var settings = value.Settings; // use this settings dictionary value on injection

            var factory = value.Factory;

            // for each below call, somehow use the values id, and settings
            value.Instance = factory.Create(id, settings);

            value.Instance.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        foreach (var value in _list.Select(item => item.Value))
        {
            value.Instance?.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```